# How to Do User Management in my Website?

Tags: asp.net

We are doing a web project for Container transaction Company. One of their requirement is User Management.The admin can set the permissions for the users. The users can only do anything according to the permissions given by the admin . How can Implement this feature.

Comment: Admin can set the permissions at what level?? Either users can navigate to certain pages or not or you need to have permissions on allowed actions on your web pages.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Membership Api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998347.aspx)

You can somewhere else store, which modules may be used by what role and you will be good to go.